# python multiprocessing.pool.map, passing arguments to spawned processes

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

```
def content_generator(applications, dict):
    for app in applications:
        yield(app, dict[app])

with open('abc.pickle', 'r') as f:
    very_large_dict = pickle.load(f)
all_applications = set(very_large_dict.keys())

pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
for result in pool.imap_unordered(func_process_application, content_generator(all_applications, very_large_dict)):
    do some aggregation on result
```

I have a really large dictionary whose keys are strings (application names), values are information concerning the application. Since applications are independent, I want to use multiprocessing to process them in parallel. Parallelization works when the dictionary is not that big but all the python processes were killed when the dictionary is too big. I used `dmesg` to check what went wrong and found they were killed since the machine ran out of memory. I did `top` when the pool processes are running and found that they all occupy the same amount of resident memory(RES), which is all 3.4G. This confuses me since it seems to have copied the whole dictionaries into the spawned processes. I thought I broke up the dictionary and passing only what is relevant to the spawned process by yielding only `dict[app]` instead of `dict`. Any thoughts on what I did wrong?

Comment: Few things you should consider: passing large amounts of data for minimal processing is not a good way to use multiprocessing.

If you have small data, that then requires long tasks, that is a better way. It sounds like your example is not a good use case, unless you have data  serialized on disk, can pass just the path and unpickle it in the process.

Next, with large files, many processing becomes a concern. Use a semaphore to avoid blowing through your memory, to limit the number of active processes.

Comment: Next: You need to consider pipe limits: A pipe is only guaranteed to have atomicity for a certain size, and once you pass that limit, you basically guarantee data corruption (like with large dictionaries):
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11946/how-big-is-the-pipe-buffer

Comment: On a Linux-y system, new processes are created by `fork()`, so get a copy of the entire parent-process address space at the time they're created.  It's "copy on write", so is more of a "virtual" copy than a "real" copy, but still ... ;-)  For a start, try creating your `Pool` _before_ creating giant data structures.  Then the child processes will inherit a much smaller address space.

Comment: Also, finally, yes: multiprocessing cannot use shared memory unless you can pass pointers to underlying C data types (without the GIL, such as numpy arrays, and then do not modify the contents of the buffer).

This means copy operations are inevitable with multiprocessing for dictionaries.

Comment: My big_dictionary is read only, processes don't need to modify them. My example is both data and computationally intensive, each application might take minutes to calculate for a single process.

Comment: @TimPeters, yes the data on *Nix systems is technically copy on write, however, reference increments do change the actual underlying object, causing a copy. That means simply using the variable will cause a copy.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, Yes, I know that I should not use shared memory, that's why I broke the dictionary up and only passed the relevant parts to a spawned process. Now the problem is that python copies not only the relevant parts but also the whole dictionary.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, I understand that, but it's irrelevant to the OP's problem - his worker processes aren't referencing `all_applications` or `very_large_dict` at all.  They are, however, inheriting them _because_ the `Pool` is created after they exist.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, he's not passing them.  He's passing `content_generator(all_applications, very_large_dict)`, which is a generator yielding one `(key, value)` pair at a time.  The generator runs in the main process.

Comment: @TimPeters Sorry I misread that. But still, it's going to duplicate an insane amount of memory regardless.

Comment: @AlexanderHuszagh, right!  That's why I keep suggesting to create the `Pool` _before_ creating the giant data structures.  Or switch to Windows so new processes get spawned instead ;-)  (BTW, in Python 3.4 or later, `spawn` _can_ be used on Linux-y systems too.)

Comment: @TimPeters Probably a good idea. Globals (and also no `if __name__ == '__main__'` guard are dangerous either way.

Honestly, I would see if it's possibly to use a numpy array at all (although it might not be suited to that). Sharing memory is extremely easy using np.ctypeslibs.as_array(), and basically gives you read-only memory without any copying.

Comment: That or pickle each key/value pair as separate entries to the stream, and then use a mutex when deserializing in a pool. The last option would have the least overhead.

Comment: @TimPeters, so in python 2.7, there is no way to spawn a new process? The big dictionary is passed in to a function as an argument and I could only create the pool inside this function. How would I be able to create the pool before the big dictionary......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comments are becoming impossible to follow, so I'm pasting in my important comment here:

On a Linux-y system, new processes are created by `fork()`, so get a copy of the entire parent-process address space at the time they're created. It's "copy on write", so is more of a "virtual" copy than a "real" copy, but still ... ;-) For a start, try creating your `Pool` before creating giant data structures. Then the child processes will inherit a much smaller address space.

Then some answers to questions:

> so in python 2.7, there is no way to spawn a new process?

On Linux-y systems, no.  The ability to use "spawn" on those was first added in Python 3.4.  On Windows systems, "spawn" has always been the only choice (no `fork()` on Windows).

> The big dictionary is passed in to a function as an argument and I
>   could only create the pool inside this function. How would I be able
>   to create the pool before the big dictionary

As simple as this:  make these two lines the first two lines in your program:

```
import multiprocessing
pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
```

You can create the pool any time you like (just so long as it exists *sometime* before you actually use it), and worker processes will inherit the entire address space *at the time* the `Pool` constructor is invoked.

### ANOTHER SUGGESTION

If you're not mutating the dict after it's created, try using this instead:

```
def content_generator(dict):
    for app in dict:
        yield app, dict[app]
```

That way you don't have to materialize a giant set of the keys either.  Or, even better (if possible), skip all that and iterate directly over the items:

```
for result in pool.imap_unordered(func_process_application, very_large_dict.iteritems()):
```